# Alternative to deprecated getCellType

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm reading an excel-file (file extension xlsx) using org.apache.poi 3.15.

This is my code:

```
try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file); XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file)) {
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();

        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "(Integer)\t");
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "(String)\t");
                    break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get a warning that `cell.getCellType()` is deprecated. Can anyone tell me the alternative?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The accepted answer shows the reason for the deprecation but misses to name the alternative:

```
CellType    getCellTypeEnum()
```

where the `CellType` is the enum decribing the type of the cell.

The plan is to rename `getCellTypeEnum()` back to `getCellType()` in POI 4.0.

Comment: Wow. This (planned) change is the direct way into future binary incompatibilities. Great! :-)  (yes, I know, you shouldn't upgrade to a new major version without checking upgrade guides etc... but it WILL be one of the first questions here as soon as POI 4.0 is out)

Comment: Yep. Although - this is a plan only, this is what is in the comments now, still might not happen. I'm not sure how much influence a publicity can have on an open source project.

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht As long as you use things like `Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC` not `0` in your switch / if statements, POI should be able to maintain source code compatibility for your code so you'd just need to recompile

Comment: @Gagravarr yes, that is exactly the definition of "binary incompatibility".

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht If you use int literals as the deprecation warning now tells you not to, you won't get source compatibility though! Also, sadly some fairly basic and deep design decisions in the JVM and java specs mean that you sometimes do have to break binary compatibility to make improvements to libraries

Comment: @Gagravarr The deprecation warning tells me not to use the int returning method at all. If I use int literals or the constants from the library makes no difference for the deprecation. Imagine the following: I write a library using POI 3.x and getCellType(). I use the constants from the library. Now, you use my library in a project, but also POI directly, and decide to upgrade to POI 4.0. You **will** get a **binary incomatibility** at **run-time**. Yeah, the error was to upgrade to POI 4.0 without checking all your dependencies. But do you really expect no one to do that error?

Comment: @TomaszStanczak What is the replacement for `cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)`?

Comment: actually CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC won't work - enum return type NUMERIC would work

Answer (score 23):

You can use:

```
cell.getCellTypeEnum()
```

Further to compare the cell type, you have to use CellType as follows:-

```
if(cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING){
      .
      .
      .
}
```

You can Refer to the documentation. Its pretty helpful:-

https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html

Comment: cell.getCellTypeEnum() is depreciated now instead use cell.getCellType() should work fine

Comment: Yes. If you're using 4.1.2, getCellTypeEnum() still work fine. but was deprecated in version 5.0.0, and moved to getCellType().

Answer (score 15):

Use getCellType()

```
switch (cell.getCellType()) {
   case BOOLEAN :
                 //To-do
                 break;
   case NUMERIC:
                 //To-do
                 break;
   case STRING:
                 //To-do
                 break;
}
```

Comment: Your code is missing another  two more types: BLANK and FORMULA  ... or add "default:"

Answer (score 10):

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Test.xlsx"));

    //create workbook instance
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

    //create a sheet object to retrieve the sheet
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    //to evaluate cell type
    FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

    for(Row row : sheet)
    {
        for(Cell cell : row)
        {
            switch(formulaEvaluator.evaluateInCell(cell).getCellTypeEnum())
            {
            case NUMERIC:
                System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");
                break;
            case STRING:
                System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                break;
            default:
                break;

            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

This code will work fine. Use `getCellTypeEnum()` and to compare use just `NUMERIC` or `STRING`.

Answer (score 8):

From the [documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCellType()):

> `int getCellType()`
>   Deprecated. POI 3.15. Will return a `CellType` enum in the future.
>
> Return the cell type. Will return `CellType` in version 4.0 of POI. For forwards compatibility, do not hard-code cell type literals in your code.

Answer (score 3):

It looks that 3.15 offers no satisfying solution: either one uses the old style with Cell.CELL_TYPE_*, or we use the method getCellTypeEnum() which is marked as deprecated.
A lot of disturbances for little add value...

Comment: You can calmly use method `getCellTypeEnum()` in 3.15. Its "Deprecated" mark is a [known bug 60228](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60228). It should be fixed in 3.16.

Comment: Strict disallowance of deprecated code = big stupid bug.

Answer (score 0):

For POI 3.17 this worked for me

```
switch (cellh.getCellTypeEnum()) {
    case FORMULA: 
        if (cellh.getCellFormula().indexOf("LINEST") >= 0) {
            value = Double.toString(cellh.getNumericCellValue());
        } else {
            value = XLS_getDataFromCellValue(evaluator.evaluate(cellh));
        }
        break;
    case NUMERIC:
        value = Double.toString(cellh.getNumericCellValue());
        break;
    case STRING:
        value = cellh.getStringCellValue();
        break;
    case BOOLEAN:
        if(cellh.getBooleanCellValue()){
            value = "true";
        } else {
            value = "false";
        }
        break;
    default:
        value = "";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do this:

```java
private String cellToString(HSSFCell cell) {
    CellType type;
    Object result;
    type = cell.getCellType();

    switch (type) {
        case NUMERIC :  //numeric value in excel
            result = cell.getNumericCellValue();
            break;
        case STRING : //String Value in Excel
            result = cell.getStringCellValue();
            break;
        default :
            throw new RuntimeException("There is no support for this type of value in Apche POI");
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Hey, welcoime to StackOverflow! As the OP already said on their post, they are getting a warning saying that `cell.getCellType()` is deprecated. Your answer is using the same method, so it is not solving this particular problem. Please consider updating it!