# What is the alternative getCellType() inside Apache POI for Excel?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want change these deprecated method:

```
    if (sheet.getRow(1).getCell(1).getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
        testSuite = "";
    } else if (sheet.getRow(1).getCell(1).getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
        double password1 = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(1).getNumericCellValue();
        testSuite = String.valueOf(password1);
    } else if (sheet.getRow(1).getCell(1).getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
        testSuite = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
    } else if (sheet.getRow(1).getCell(1).getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) {
        testSuite = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
    }
```

[image]
I see inside source:

```
/**
 * Return the cell type.
 * 
 * Will return {@link CellType} in a future version of POI.
 * For forwards compatibility, do not hard-code cell type literals in your code.
 *
 * @return the cell type
 * @deprecated 3.15. Will return a {@link CellType} enum in the future.
 */
@Override
public int getCellType() {
    return getCellTypeEnum().getCode();
}
```

Comment: Please refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993683/alternative-to-deprecated-getcelltype

Comment: thank you, it is helpful information!