# Selenium: Solution to depreciated methods getCellType() and getCellTypeEnum()

Tags: java, parsing, selenium, apache-poi

I am new to Selenium and trying to write a program to extract values from excel file.  My data is in the first sheet in the 1st column.  I see the `getCellType()` and `getCellEnum()` both are depreciated and will  get a fix in  POI 4.0. Till that time the fix is available,  what is the way I can  extract the cell values and then compare the value in the Web application. The cell data can be int or String.

Comment: I had checked the post at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993683/alternative-to-deprecated-getcelltype, but still quite did understand how I resolve the issue as I am still new and learnng..  Also  Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC and CELL_TYPE_STRING is depreciated. Probably

Comment: Below is the code I wrote:

Comment: Iterator<Row> ir = sh.iterator(); //sh is sheet
Iterator<WebElement> it = list1.iterator();//  List<WebElement> in web app
Row rowpointer = ir.next();
while (ir.hasNext()) {// iterating over ethe rows in the excel
rowpointer = ir.next();
Iterator<Cell> c1 = rowpointer.iterator();
while (c1.hasNext()) { 
Cell cell = c1.next();
RichTextString rs1 = cell.getRichStringCellValue();
while (it.hasNext()) {
WebElement we = it.next();
String ex1 = we.getText();
if (rs1.getString().equals(ex1)) {
we.click();
it = list1.iterator();
break;
}}}}
what if cells type was not known ?