# Depreciated CellType method

Tags: java, excel, apache

I've seen other forums here with suggestions for solutions I don't get any of them to work.

I want to check if a cell is either **null or blank**, the depriciated code that I use is (both getCellType() and CELL_TYPE_BLANK is depreciated):

```
if( (c == null) || c.getCellType() == c.CELL_TYPE_BLANK){
//do something
}
```

**For example I've been looking at solution in this thread:**

> [Alternative to deprecated getCellType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993683/alternative-to-deprecated-getcelltype)

and I was thinking that a solution could possibly look like this:

```
if( (c == null) || c.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.BLANK){
//Error: incomparable types: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType and int
//do something
}
```

**or**

```
if( (c == null) || c.getBooleanCellValue()){
//do something
}
```

but it does'nt work and apaches documentation is not that helpful either. Does anyone have a solution that does'nt produce warnings? I'm using poi 3.17.

BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been struggling with the same issue and I found the following works for me.

It is the inverse of your approach.
I check if the value is not null.

The code below is for handling string values:

```
private static String checkForNullString(Cell cellToCheck) {
    String strCheck;
    if (cellToCheck != null && cellToCheck.getCellTypeEnum() != CellType.BLANK) {
        cellToCheck.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
        strCheck = cellToCheck.getStringCellValue();
    }
    else
        strCheck = "";
    return strCheck;
}
```

To handle numeric values, simply change the following:

```
cellToCheck.getStringCellValue();
```

to

```
cellToCheck.getNumericCellValue());
```