# reading values form excel with single row with multiple columns

Tags: java

How about reading the row with multiple values using excel

for instance

| reference | testcase1 | testcase2 | testcase3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name | Sam | ram | cam |
| Age | 20 | 25 | 30 |
| sex | m | F | m |
| place | place1 | place2 | place 3 |

I have to read

```
testcase1.name=sam
testcase2.name=ram
testcase3.name=cam
```

and age

how can I do this... any help would be appreciated

Comment: You may use Apache POI library for parsing Excel: https://poi.apache.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use apache poi library.

First you must read the Excel file in a java object

```
        FileInputStream myFile = new FileInputStream(new File(FILE_NAME));
        Workbook myWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(myFile);
        Sheet datatypeSheet = myWorkbook.getSheetAt(0); //read the first sheet
        Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();
```

Then you can iterate over each row and in each row you can read each cell (aka column value)

```
    List<TestCase> myList = new ArrayList();
    int rowNum = 0;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                Row row = iterator.next();
                int columnsSize = row.getLastCellNum();

                //create all objects
                if(rowNum == 0) {
                  for (int i = 1; i <= columnsSize; i++) {
                     myList.add(new TestCase());
                  }
                } else {
                   //initialize property in each row for all objects
                     for (int i = 1; i <= columnsSize; i++) {
                        TestCase testCase = myList.get(i-1);

int cellType = row.getCell(i).getCellType();
switch(cellType) {
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
       testCase.properties.add(new Property(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue(), 
       String.valueOf(row.getCell(i).getNumericCellValue()));
        break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
        testCase.properties.add(new Property(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue(), 
        row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue());
        break;
}
                  }
               }

             rowNum++;     
             }
System.out.println(myList);

   

  

    public class TestCase {
    public List<Property> properties;

    public TestCase(){
    this.properties = new ArrayList();
                     }
    }

    public class Property {
    String name;
    String value;

     public Property(String name, String value){
     this.name = name;
     this.value = value;
    }
        }
```

*Edit: For loop must have <= condition instead of <

Comment: thanks for your code..  I need run through the multiple rows and it will be a Loop.. can we add for loop  after adding into the list? could you please help me with that?

Comment: You can loop again after the first loop. You should only ask for a new iterator with iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator(). Then you can loop again every row for a second time using a similar code as the above.

Comment: Not able to add to array it says "Cannot instantiate the type Row" any fix for this

Comment: What are you trying to do with Row that brings this error? Do you run the code as posted to this answer or something different?

Comment: I executed  the code pasted by you.. am not able to add to list... Could you say me  what is  "List<TestCase> myList = new ArrayList();  TestCase  means..

Comment: TestCase is a Class that should contain the fields name, age, sex, place so you can group all those information for each object. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Appreicate your answer, however my in my case , I cannot limit to the fields, it could any number of fields.                                                                                                                     well you mean to say that i can pass whatever value I needed and get the a value of the field?

Comment: See my updated answer. This should do exactly what you plan to do. In the end you will have in each TestCase a dynamic field of properties with name and value. So name of property in your example will be Name in first row, Age in second row ...

Comment: please mark the updated answer as accepted answer if it has solved the problem

Comment: hello .. thanks for the  response .. Now I dont see any  errors in your code. one question  How do i Pass get the values in my Tests                                                             I would like to use Testcase1.name in my frist test and Testcase2.name in my second testcse ,, how do i get the values there .. to use it as Test data

Comment: You should read the list that contains this info. myList.get(0).name will be Testcase1.name because TestCase1 as you see it in your excel will be the first element of the array.

Comment: this is how am calling  in my tests t get the values List<Testcase> myList = new ArrayList();
   myList = readclassexcel.readexcel();
   
   for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++)
   {
       System.out.println("testdata from excel"+myList.get(i));
   }                                                                                                                           where readexcelis the method  name . however it is returning null with exception.

Comment: one last  issue is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell   I can use Dataformatter, however am not  sure how to use it ,,could you please help me on this.

Comment: check updated answer. It should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer am getting The method getCellTypeEnum() is undefined for the type Cell  and for the cell it is coming as Cannot switch on a value of type CellType. Only convertible int values, strings or enum variables are                                                              and where should we pass the Numeric and String

Comment: try to fix what is not compatible by reading here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993683/alternative-to-deprecated-getcelltype

Comment: Thank you ,, where to pass NUMERIC and STRING in Switch  case.   and thank you so much for fixing all the issues

Comment: Your excel file contains numeric values on the second row of AGE. If you convert your excel to contain only string values then the library will not have any issue. If you wish to have your excel file as it is you have to make a switch case and check before reading. If the cell contain a numeric value you must read it with getNumericCellValue() and if it has a string value you must retrieve it with getStringCellValue()

Comment: NUMERIC cannot be resolved to a variable                                                                         STRING cannot be resolved to a variable .. how to close this... i just copy and paste your code..

Comment: thank you so much again.. the code is working  like charm....                                               however how can i get the value like                                                         Testcase1.name = Sam                                                                                      Testcase2.name  = Ram .                                                                                                        Testcase3.name = Cam in my class ..i need to use the values for my  selenium tests

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial might be helpful to use: https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-read-excel-file-in-java.

Basically, you are using the Apache POI Library to parse the file's values, generating iterators for each row, then for each cell in each row, and dealing with the data that way.

In your case, after importing the relevant Classes, the code snippet will be something like this:

```java
//Input Data for Class
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("<File Location>.xls(x)"));

// Create an Apache POI Workbook reading the file
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(in);

// Use the Workbook to make a sheet
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0); // Replace 0 with your sheet number

List<Row> rowsList = new ArrayList<Row>();
sheet.iterator().forEachRemaining(actualList::add); // Gets a list of all the rows

int i = -1;
String[] names = new String[3];

for (Cell cell : rowsList[1]) { // Start at second row
    if (i++ > 0) {
        names[i] = cell.getStringCellValue();
    }
}

testcase1.name = names[0];
testcase2.name = names[1];
testcase3.name = names[2];

i = -1;
int[] ages = new int[3];

for (Cell cell : rowsList[2]) { // Start at Third Row
    if (i++ > 0) {
        ages[i] = (int) cell.getNumericCellValue();
    }
}

testcase1.name = ages[0];
testcase2.name = ages[1];
testcase3.name = ages[2];
```