# case CellType.STRING: case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC: case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK: not working and also tried CellType.STRING but no use still errors

Tags: java, file-handling

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viTr5.png)

case CellType.STRING:
case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK: not working and also tried CellType.STRING but no use still
errors.

Comment: case CellType.STRING:
     System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
     break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
     System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
     break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
     System.out.println("--");
     break;

Comment: Copy entire class (with imports) and format code using " { } " option from the editor. With this, we can't do much.

Comment: Please do not put code as images. Paste it as formatted text (by editing your question).

Comment: Also include information about what the actual error is.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the following code:

```
switch (cell.getCellTypeEnum()) {
   case STRING:
      break;
   case NUMERIC:
      break;
   case BLANK:
      break;
   default:
      break;
}
```

getCellType is deprecated and shouldn´t be used anymore. See following post:
[Alternative to deprecated getCellType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993683/alternative-to-deprecated-getcelltype)

[image]

Comment: But this is also showing deprecated juran

Comment: Please provide the full code and the poi version you´re using.